# Pipreqs not including all packages?

Tags: python, pip, conda, requirements.txt

I currently have a conda environment `tf_gpu` and I pip installed `pipreqs` in it to auto generate `requirements.txt`

Now, in my project folder, I have `app.py` with the imports :

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, request
from predict import get_recs
import urllib.request
```

Also, `predict` uses `pandas, scipy, numpy, pickle`

So, but the `requirements.txt` generated by pipreqs using `pipreqs ./` inside the project folder only gets me the following:

```
Flask==2.1.3
numpy==1.23.3
pandas==1.4.4
scipy==1.9.1
```

Why is `python-dotenv` not included? It isnt a standard library right? So what's happening here?

Comment: No idea. This question is probably out of scope for StackOverflow anyway. You can ask on [_`pipreqs`_ ticket tracker](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues). Maybe you can also try with [_`pigar`_](https://pypi.org/project/pigar/) instead.

Comment: Was `python-dotenv` installed with `conda`? Are you sure `pipreqs` lists packages installed with `conda`?

Comment: pipreqs should list packages installed with conda

Comment: pipreqs does miss packages, and will also add non-sensical ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [open issues in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs/issues), some packages don't map well. You could try opening an issue for this package.